# code to sort a list of links in different drivers

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a code that does this:
I have a site from which I take a list of links, let's say I take 50
of these 50 I want to use only 30 so I say to my code

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_partial_link:
    driver_"x".get (i)
    a=+1
    if a==30:
        break
```

where x is to indicate the number of the used driver that goes from 1-30.

My problem is that the code reads that variable x as such, if I declare the 30 drivers at the beginning of the code as

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path = "path")
driver_1 = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path = "path")
driver_2 = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path = "path")
ecc....
```

how can I make x to be read as a number and not as part of another variable called driver_x

if there is no way, what could be an alternative?

Comment: Investigate data driven testing. Write one script and pass in the list of links. Each test case will spawn its own driver and do the testing for that one site.

Comment: can u explain better to me how it works?